# Why do I see stale files on my MacBook Air 13 when I use 'Android File Transfer'?

Tags: android

Why do I see stale files on my MacBook Air 13 when I use 'Android File Transfer'?

I have a LG Volt (LGLS740) running Android 4.4.2.  The MacBook Air 13 is running OS X Yosemite (10.10.2) & has app 'Android File Transfer' installed (Version 1.0.50.2266).  When I connect the Android phone to the MacBook Air 13 via the USB cable I see stale files in 'Internal storage/Android/data/com.StyleTap.StyleTap/import' that I don't see when I use app 'File Manager' on the Android phone.  I am using the Palm emulator from 'www.styletap.com', but I don't believe that the stale files are specific to this usage.

Comment: what is a "stale file" ?

Comment: By "stale file" I mean one that had once been in the "import" folder in the 'Android File Transfer' list of files but is no longer there--according to the local file manager on the Android phone.  Such files have been imported into the Styletap Palm emulator on the Android phone.